# impala CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and remove double quotes

Tags: hive, hdfs, cloudera, impala

i got data on CSV for example :
"Female","44","0","0","Yes","Govt_job","Urban","103.59","32.7","formerly smoked"

i put it as hdfs with hdfs dfs put

and now i want to create external table from it on impala (not in hive)
there is an option without the double quotes ?

this is what i run by impala-shell:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_test.test1_ext
( `gender` STRING,`age` STRING,`hypertension` STRING,`heart_disease` STRING,`ever_married` STRING,`work_type` STRING,`Residence_type` STRING,`avg_glucose_level` STRING,`bmi` STRING,`smoking_status` STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION "/user/test/tmp/test1"
```

> Update 28.11

i managed to do it by create the external and then create a VIEW as select with case when concat() each col.

Answer (score 2):

Impala uses the Hive metastore so anything created in Hive is available from Impala after issuing an INVALIDATE METADATA dbname.tablename. HOWEVER, to remove the quotes you need to use the Hive Serde library 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' and this is not accessible from Impala. My suggestion would be to do the following:

1. Create the external table in Hive

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_test.test1_ext
   ( gender STRING, age STRING, hypertension STRING, heart_disease  STRING, ever_married  STRING, work_type  STRING, Residence_type  STRING, avg_glucose_level  STRING, bmi  STRING, smoking_status  STRING  )
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
   (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = """
   )
   STORED AS TEXTFILE
   LOCATION "/user/test/tmp/test1"
2. Create a managed table in Hive using CTAS

   CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT * FROM test_test.test1_ext;
3. Make it available in Impala

   INVALIDATE METADATA db.mytable;

Comment: by this approach i need to create table with all the data into it.

my suggestion is to create external on impala and then create view with case when concat() each col.

Comment: You can't use the SERDE in Impala as my answer states

Comment: i dont need to use a serde by my approach